# How can I incorporate non-NPM js into SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, es6-modules, sveltekit

I'm asking the question generally because I'm interested in understanding how this stuff works, not just solving my immediate problem.

That said, nothing is quite so clarifying as a concrete issue, so here's where I'm stuck, in case the particulars are helpful. I'm trying to get the "liquid text" library, Blotter.js, working in a SvelteKit project, but can only seem to get it working with Svelte (no Kit).

It feels like I'm probably just going about this all wrong. If you're willing to show me some true mercy, please try forking my tiny test projects & running `npm run dev` to see how the same code works in one environment, but not the other :

- https://github.com/nvlgzr/blotter-svelte-test  Svelte
- https://github.com/nvlgzr/blotter-sveltekit-test  SvelteKit

  ↑ Gives error: `Blotter is not defined`

Fwiw, here are Blotter's official usage instructions: https://github.com/bradley/Blotter#usage

Answer (score 1):

Svelte is a library to renders component. I can't be used alone.

Sveltekit is like an application server. It uses svelte to render components, but supports all the scope of a traditional application (like routing, ssr, webservices, ..).

By default, sveltekit try to render a route in the server (in a node environment) and then hydrate it in the client for interactivity.

Your library (Blotter) doesn't work in a node environment / serverside. You have to add a logic to not render component using Blotter in the server. It's described in the FAQ here: https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#how-do-i-use-a-client-side-only-library-that-depends-on-document-or-window

- use `$app/browser` to check if you are running in the server or in a browser
- use `onMount` which is called only in a browser